# Using embedded framework in Xcode 6.1 results in app crashing with mapped file has no team identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

We created a framework that we use for our iOS projects. In the general tab you can see it as an embedded binary.

[image: Embedded binary]

In the build phases tab it shows up as an embedded framework:

[image: Build phase]

After archiving the project and installing the ipa file on a device and then launching the app I see the following error in the device console:

[deny-mmap] mapped file has no team identifier and is not a platform binary: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CE2542E1-355A-4A45-AC97-08A2330B45E5/Policy Pal.app/Frameworks/MTKit.framework/MTKit

Please help! I haven't seen anybody come across this problem before.

Comment: Did you solve this yet?

Answer (score 4):

We are seeing this too. According to [this blog](https://www.airsignapp.com/ios-apps-using-swift-crash-when-signed-with-inhouse-certificate/) you need to revoke and re-generate your certificate and mobile provisioning file. We haven't tried it yet, but the symptoms are the same.

EDIT: Our build-meister did this a few weeks ago and it does indeed fix the problem.

Comment: Same here, some problem when I do a entrerpise build.

Comment: Also officially acknowledged by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1886/_index.html